# Goethe: Sprachen "kennen" instead of "können"?

Tags: word-usage

Goethe wrote in *Maximen und Reflexionen*:

> Wer fremde Sprachen nicht kennt, weiß nichts von seiner eigenen.

(See [Wikiquote](https://de.wikiquote.org/wiki/Johann_Wolfgang_von_Goethe#Sonstiges_alphabetisch_geordnet).)

What is striking is the use of the verb "kennen" instead of "können". Was this the preferred verb for expressing language competence in Goethe's time?

Answer (score 3):

No, I wouldn't say it was the preferred verb for this. Even at Goethe's time, the following expressions would have been much more frequent:

- *eine Sprache beherrschen (to have command of a language)*
- *einer Sprache mächtig sein (to have mastered a language)*
- *eine Sprache zu sprechen vermögen (to be able to speak a language)*

You can find evidence of the latter phrase ("vermögen") in Adelung's 18th century dictionary, which defines language as "Das Vermögen zu sprechen." (http://lexika.digitale-sammlungen.de/adelung/lemma/bsb00009134_2_1_1744)

However, most of the above phrases are rather "bulky": they consist of more than just one verb and will inevitably bloat any sentence that uses them. This would have taken away much of the elegance of Goethe's aphorism: his words cleverly link together two antonyms [*fremde (foreign)* vs. *eigene (your own)*] by having two synonyms "crash" into one another at the centre of his sentence:

> Wer fremde Sprachen nicht **kennt, weiß** nichts von seiner eigenen.

The use of the verb *können* would have caused similar problems: since it's a modal verb, it requires a full verb complement - *eine Sprache **sprechen** können* - which again would have bloated the sentence. The ellipsis *eine Sprache können* (which omits the full verb) is most likely a more modern phenomenon and may have sounded ungrammatical to 18th century ears.

So, while it may have been syntax that made Goethe look for another verb to use here, it was *semantics* that actually permitted him to do so. Historically, both *kennen* and *können* have always had a very similar meaning: at the earliest stages, both were about knowledge, rather than physical ability.
(cf. Duden's "Herkunft" section for evidence:
http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/kennen
http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/koennen)

Hence, exchanging one for the other makes a lot of sense syntactically and does not cause much disturbance semantically.